# Java/Groovy : Elegant way of initializing method with a class

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods, groovy, initialization

Taking into consideration that I do not want to use static methods, which would be the best or most elegant way of invoking a method? In order to invoke a method I need also to instantiate the class.

What I am currently doing is the following. I am passing the needed parameters to the class and afterwards the same needed parameters to the method.

This is what I am doing:

```
boolean switchOffButton= new Light(script, data, lightsOn, lightsOff).calculateLightIlumination(script, DataHooks, lightsOn, lightsOff)
```

Do you think I could improve this in any way?Maybe applying a specific design pattern?

Thanks,

Kat

Comment: Hi Kat... do you mean you "do **not** want to use static methods" ? Also, if you're asking about making that more idiomatic/elegant in Groovy, I suspect it will come down to opinion and a bit more context about the usage. For example, will the `Light` object be used again?

Comment: Hi Micahel, indeed, I meant "I do not want to use static". The light object will be used in further calculations

Comment: why don't you store the constructor params as fields, so that you can call the method with no params?